# progressbar never shows

Tags: android

I want my `ProgressDialog` to show a circular `progressbar` but It never shows. What is the problem with my code?

I am using   `.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);`

here is the full code:

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NSOMCK.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);// this crash due to going back before the announcements load
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.show();
```

Comment: what is "NSOMCK.this"?

Comment: @maxwellnewage my activity's name.

Comment: please add the layout code

Comment: there is no layout for the dialog.